# declaration of 2d array in the class and its latter usage

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to have a declaration of 2d array in private part of my class and then latter on, the functions of this class will use and modify the values in the array, but I am getting an error which says "I-value specified const object". What is wrong with this code and how can I fix it?

Here is a simple code demonstrating my problem

in someClass.h________________

```
class someClass
{
public:
    //Some code here

private:

    char grid[20][20];

    //Some code here

}
```

in someClass.cpp______________

lets say one of the functions is trying to reassign the value of item in position (0,0) like so.

```
grid[0][0]='*';
```

This gives me an error saying, expression must be modifiable lvalue.

Comment: Show the whole definition of that function please.

Comment: Somehow I suspect the object being worked on is accessed via a `const someClass&` or the code in question is in a member function declared `const`. (ok, yea, the "I-value specified const object" message was kind of a giveaway on that).

Comment: I am pretty sure that neither class nore the variable are not const.

Answer (score 0):

Move it from private to public so you can access it outside the class. If it is private then only functions inside the class can use it.

Comment: All i need is class functions to access it, there is no need for it to be public.